# How can I add advanced animations to my mobile app?

Tags: android, ios, animation, animated-gif

I would like to add *"advanced"* animations to my mobile apps. Something like this one:

[image: Animation example]

*(I have slowed down the animation to 30% to make the effects more visible)*

I am working both with iOS 10+ and Android. However, for now iOS is more important to me so let concentrate on this.

Creating the first part of the example animation (fading in book, envelope, etc.) using basic `UIAnimations` would be possible but already quite difficult (e.g. the parallax effect of the shadows). I have now Idea how to create the second part with the paper stacks.

Sure, this could also be done using `UIAnimations` but it would be insanely complex, wouln'd it?

**So, how to get such animations into an app?**

Are there any tools, formats, etc. to create such animations outside of Xcode and to import them? I only know GIF to animate images but this a quite old and limited format.

The app I found these animations in seems to control them very precisely. For example it controls when an animation starts. Additionally the animations looks great on different devices in different sizes and resolutions.

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the animation from "After Effects" and run it through [Lottie](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android).

Lottie renders "After Effects" animations natively on Android and iOS, Web, and React Native

You can refer [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@christopherdeane/native-app-animations-in-android-studio-using-lottie-from-airbnb-bbc039c87e63) for more info.